# Estimating Average HR from PPG sensor

Tags: fft, frequency, power-spectral-density, time-frequency, time-series

I am reading [Smartphone based Blood Pressure Monitoring via the Oscillometric Finger Pressing Method](https://stm.sciencemag.org/content/10/431/eaap8674), which is trying to estimate blood pressure from a PPG sensor and a small applied force finger sensor. I am not an engineer, so I'm unfamiliar with a lot of the terminology.

In this paper, they describe using the ppg sensor measurements to estimate an average heart rate. The single sentence that describes this process is *"The average heart rate is determined
from the blood volume waveform based on its spectral peaks within the
frequency range of 0.5 to 3 Hz".*

I have a ppg sensor, so I can take a time series measurement of the blood volume, but frankly, I have no idea what this sentence means other than it involves some kind of spectral analysis. I'm unable to find any similar descriptions of this algorithm in google scholar. I would really appreciate it if someone could interpret and translate this sentence into either an algorithmic, or statistical terminology, which I am much more familiar.

Comment: What's PPG sensor?